# How to User data stored in Cognito with DynamoDb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

So we are going to be using AWS Cognito to authenticate users in our app. However this brings me to the question of how to interact with the cognito user data with DyanmoDB and/or MongoDB?

In our specific case, I wanted to create a list of 25+ Company records in DynamoDB, and then when user signs up, they will have to pick one of these companies to be associated with in the user profile. However, I don't see a way to link Identity Pool custom attributes with a dynamoDB table.

Also, whenever the user makes a submission, I want the user to be associated with the submission either in dynamoDB or mongoDB.

What is the best approach for both of these topics? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using the custom attributes in Cognito. So:

1. Assign a custom attribute: `company` (Get DynamoDB record when you need it with each user)
2. And then in DyanmoDB you can store the submission record in DynamoDB with a field being the users email address (not really recommended, for security reasons) or a hash of the user's email address. [ Or as Jeff mentioned in comments, use the sub generated by Cognito, as it is unattributable and unique! ]

By doing this, you can have a user related to a company in a DynamoDB Table and submissions in a DynamoDB table.

Comment: Cognito dev here, this answer is pretty sound. Just one suggested alternative for the key: the user sub has no personal information and is globally unique.

Comment: Oh that is a good point! Using the sub created by Cognito would be a better, unattributable key. Thanks @JeffBailey !